# Converting array-formatted string input to string array efficiently

Tags: java, arrays, string

Say one has string input in the form below:

```
{ 'OTH', 'REJ', 'RSTO', 'RSTOS0', 'RSTR', 'S0', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'SF', 'SH' }
```

What would be an efficient way to convert it to an array of Strings with each element being `OTH`, `REJ`, etc.?

I've currently done this using `String.replace()` and `String.split()` and have also considered the use of regex-s for the same, but was wondering whether there was a more easier/intuitive way of doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of `replace` and `split` will need to iterate over your entire string which means you will need to iterate over it twice. With `Scanner` you can do it in one go, but you will need to use delimiter representing non-word characters (non `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9` `_`) which can be written in regex as `\\W`.

So your code can look like

```
String text = "{ 'OTH', 'REJ', 'RSTO', 'RSTOS0', 'RSTR', 'S0', 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'SF', 'SH' }";
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
sc.useDelimiter("\\W+");// one or more non-word character
while(sc.hasNext())
    tokens.add(sc.next());

System.out.println(tokens);//[OTH, REJ, RSTO, RSTOS0, RSTR, S0, S1, S2, S3, SF, SH]
sc.close();
```